# How to check user email address valid or not in django can anyone have idea to check user interring email address is valid or not

Tags: python, django

> How we can know user email address is valid or not without sending a link is there any method to do this in django , i just try to check the user their email address is valid or not .

Comment: Valid in what scenes. Proper email format or to check email exists

Comment: to check email address exist or not

Comment: You can search the string @ at least. You can have your server extract mx records from the domain to connect to the server and simulate sending a message.

Comment: you can try this package --> https://pypi.org/project/validate_email/

Comment: Your Question is about Email and you mentioned error of Error installing Pydnas. What is your Exact Question ?

Comment: i get answer  `from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.core.validators import validate_email` it validate email existance fine